# How to append contents of two word document?

Tags: java, file, ms-word

Reading a word document for example *SampleOne.doc* and storing it in to a `byte[]`.

```
@Column(name = "LETTER_WORD_EDITOR_VALUE")
private byte[] letterWordEditorValue;
```

It is a `blob` in DB.

I want to read the contents of another word document for Example *SampleTwo.doc* as `byte[]` and appending both the `byte[]` and setting the resultant `byte[]` in to  `letterWordEditorValue`.

Below is the code to do that.

```
 FileInputStream fileRead = new FileInputStream(fileNameWithPath);

 byte[] readData=IOUtils.toByteArray(fileRead);
 byte[] one = readData;

 byte[] two = inquiryCor.getLetterWordEditorValue();
 byte[] combined = new byte[one.length + two.length];

 System.arraycopy(one,0,combined,0,one.length);
 System.arraycopy(two,0,combined,one.length,two.length);

 inquiryCor.setLetterWordEditorValue(combined);
```

Below is the code to read the `letterWordEditorValue` and writing in to a Word-File.

```
fileEditOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileNameWithPath);                               
fileEditOutPutStream.write(inquiryCor.getLetterWordEditorValue());
fileEditOutPutStream.close();
```

The contents of word file is not the contents of one+two, Rather it contents `readData` value only. But when printing the `combined.length` `i.e resultant length` is printing sum of *one.length+two.length*.

Why above code is not appending contents of two word document?

What am i doing wrong? Please guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: its not possible to combine two proprietary documents via simple bytearray-concatenation ... that would'nt even make any sense ... You need to parse the two documents via some library and put them together manually. What you were trying to do is like trying to use two motors inside of one car by attaching a second car to the first one ... does not compute!

Comment: @specializt Can't we do that without using third party library? Is there any way to do that without using third party library? If you suggest some solution would be better.

Comment: No. Thats what the word "impossible" means. Word documents are not supported by java without using libraries

Comment: @specializt _'two motors inside of one car by attaching a second car to the first one ... does not compute!'_ but it is computing in case of simple text file. Thanks for the suggestion, I will use libraries to do that.

Comment: thats because textfiles are no proprietary documents. They're textfiles.

Comment: Are you actually referring to MS Word documents? If so you should attach the "ms-word" tag to your question. And @specializt may want to consider turning her comment into an answer, which you can then accept. Simple concatenation just does not make sense here.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need a third-party library if you do all of the things that a third-party library would do. The word _impossible_ is a bit too strong here. _Exceedingly difficult and time-consuming (on the order of person-years of effort)_ would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to combine two proprietary documents via simple bytearray-concatenation. That wouldn't even make any sense. You need to parse the two documents via some library and put them together manually. What you were trying to do is like trying to use two motors inside of one car by attaching a second car to the first one ... does not compute!

Apache offers a library for office documents : https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: I have some close contact with users of the POI library. It is quite useful. This is a very good suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Replace

```
fileEditOutPutStream.write(inquiryCor.getLetterWordEditorValue());
```

with

```
fileEditOutPutStream.write(inquiryCorrespondence.getLetterWordEditorValue());
```

Comment: Sorry. It is a copy paste error.Edited the code.So replacing of this won't work.

Comment: Alright, I think the problem is in this area:
[inquiryCor.getLetterWordEditorValue()]


try to print the elements returned by this method alone and see what you get.

I suspect that you get white spaces or something.